# Filtering URLs obtained using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm writing a program and the goal is to get the captions of links from a website, but only if that link is to certain website.

I can, so far, use BeautifulSoup to grab a list of the anchor tags on the page (including the href="url" bits) and I'd like to filter them out, preferably with a regex.

The links I want to grab are in the format: "http://section.website.com/123456" where 123456 is any 6 digit number. I have tried the code underneath, but nothing is appended to the data array.

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re

opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]

url = ('http://awebsite.com')

ourUrl = opener.open(url).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(ourUrl)

links = soup.findAll('a')
data = []
for i in links:
    print i
for i in links:
    if "http://section.website.com/\d+" in i:
        data.append(i.text)
for entry in data:
    print entry

raw_input()
```

Comment: Any specific reason why you are using BeautifulSoup 3? It was mothballed years ago, and BeautifulSoup 4 gives you more flexibility here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leave the filtering entirely to BeautifulSoup:

```
links = soup.findAll('a', href=re.compile('^http://section.website.com/\d{6}$'))
```

This'll only match links that have *exactly* 6 digits, and no other links will be included in the result set.

Your code failed because you need to test against the `href` attribute instead, and you were not using a regular expression, just plain text. The following would go part of the way towards filtering without a regular expression:

```
if "http://section.website.com/" in i.get('href', ''):
```

but that would not test for digits, or test for if the URL properly started with that text.

You may want to upgrade to BeautifulSoup version 4; you are using BeautifulSoup 3, which was mothballed over 2 years ago. All new features and bugfixes go to version 4 instead.